# How can I root from the front end to my controller

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I have a problem with a project for my school.
I want to hide a button if the connectedUser had already vote for a post.
my fonctions on my controller is obviously not use (I tried to put a Console.Writeline("blabla") to try but no "blabla" on my console so I guess it's a problem with my root but I don't understand how to do it properly

this is my button in the html :

```
               <button [hidden]="getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus(post.id)" mat-icon-button>
                    <mat-icon  (click)="down(post.id)">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
                </button>
```

this is my fonction in the ts file:

```
getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus(postId : number){
    this.postService.getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus(postId, this.getCurrentUserId);
}
```

this is my fonction in post.service.ts :

```
  public getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus(postId : number , userId : number){
    return this.http.get<boolean>(`${this.baseUrl}api/posts/getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus/${postId}/${userId}`)
  }
```

and this is in my controller :

```
[HttpGet("getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus/{postId}/{authorId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus(int postId, int UserId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("blabla");
            Console.WriteLine("post id =" + postId + "userId =" + UserId + "");
            var vote = await _context.Votes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(v => v.PostId == postId && v.AuthorId == UserId && v.UpDown == 1);
            Console.WriteLine(vote.AuthorId);
            if (vote != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I spend hours to find where is my problem and I become crazy ! I probably didn't understood something to  make my root so if someone can help me it would be great !

thank you

edit : here is all my PostsController.cs (as asked in a comment) :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using prid1920_projet.Models;
using PRID_Framework;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace prid1920_projet.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PostsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly PridContext _context;
        public PostsController(PridContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PostDTO>>> GetQuestions()
        {
            var questions = (from q in _context.Posts where q.ParentId == null select q);
            return (await questions.ToListAsync()).ToDTO();
        }

        //[Authorized(Role.Admin)]
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<PostDTO>> GetById(int id)
        {
            var post = await _context.Posts.FindAsync(id);
            if (post == null)
                return NotFound();
            return post.ToDTO();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<PostDTO>> PostPost(PostDTO data)
        {
            var userPseudo = User.Identity.Name;
            var newPost = new Post()
            {
                Author = (from u in _context.Users where u.Pseudo == userPseudo select u).FirstOrDefault(),
                Title = data.Title,
                Body = data.Body,
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                ParentId = data.parentId,

                //postTags ??

            };
            _context.Posts.Add(newPost);
            var res = await _context.SaveChangesAsyncWithValidation();
            if (!res.IsEmpty)
                return BadRequest(res);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = newPost.Id }, newPost.ToDTO());
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("accept/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Accept(int id)
        {
            var post = await _context.Posts.FindAsync(id);
            if (post == null)
                return NotFound();
            var postParent = await _context.Posts.FindAsync(post.ParentId);
            if (postParent == null)
                return NotFound();
            postParent.AcceptedAnswerId = id;
            var res = await _context.SaveChangesAsyncWithValidation();
            if (!res.IsEmpty)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("up/{postId}/{authorId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Up(int postId, int authorId)
        {
            var vote = await _context.Votes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PostId == postId && p.AuthorId == authorId);
            if (vote != null)
            {
                vote.UpDown = +1;
            }
            else
            {
                Vote newVote = new Vote()
                {
                    UpDown = 1,
                    AuthorId = authorId,
                    PostId = postId
                };
                _context.Votes.Add(newVote);
            }
            var res = await _context.SaveChangesAsyncWithValidation();
            if (!res.IsEmpty)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("down/{postId}/{authorId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Down(int postId, int authorId)
        {
            var vote = await _context.Votes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PostId == postId && p.AuthorId == authorId);
            if (vote != null)
            {
                vote.UpDown = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                Vote newVote = new Vote()
                {
                    UpDown = -1,
                    AuthorId = authorId,
                    PostId = postId
                };
                _context.Votes.Add(newVote);
            }
            var res = await _context.SaveChangesAsyncWithValidation();
            if (!res.IsEmpty)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("clear/{postId}/{authorId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Clear(int postId, int authorId)
        {
            var vote = await _context.Votes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PostId == postId && p.AuthorId == authorId);
            if (vote.UpDown == 1 || vote.UpDown == -1)
            {
                _context.Remove(vote);
            }
            var res = await _context.SaveChangesAsyncWithValidation();
            if (!res.IsEmpty)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        [HttpGet("getVoteForPostConnectedUserMinus/{postId}/{authorId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> getVoteForPostConnectedUserMinus(int postId, int userId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("prout");
            Console.WriteLine("post id =" + postId + "userId =" + userId + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            var vote = await _context.Votes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(v => v.PostId == postId && v.AuthorId == userId && v.UpDown == -1);
            Console.WriteLine(vote + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            if (vote != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        [HttpGet("getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus/{postId}/{authorId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus(int postId, int UserId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("blabla");
            Console.WriteLine("post id =" + postId + "userId =" + UserId + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            var vote = await _context.Votes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(v => v.PostId == postId && v.AuthorId == UserId && v.UpDown == 1);
            Console.WriteLine(vote.AuthorId + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            if (vote != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
         [HttpGet("{postId}/{authorId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> getVoteForPostConnectedUser(int postId, int UserId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("prout");
            Console.WriteLine("post id =" + postId + "userId =" + UserId + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            var vote = await _context.Votes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(v => v.PostId == postId && v.AuthorId == UserId);
            Console.WriteLine(vote.AuthorId + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            if (vote != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I assume `getVoteForPostConnectedUserMinus` is the same or similar as `getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus` you are missing `return`

Comment: ahah yes, sorry I messed up when I copy the code but yes it's similar fonction

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the controller cs file? I have a hunch that your path is missing a '/' between the base URL and 'api' that is defined in the TS file

Comment: I edit my post to had the controller, just the 3 last function doesn't work (they are all 3 very similar) the rest of the code work great.

Comment: Okay if you breakpoint in that function. Does it actually reach that endpoint? You can check in the debugger window of your browser and see if it actually responded or if it is a 404.

Comment: I had a breakpoint but I don't see anything but i'm pretty sure that my functions in the controller is never use because of my console.writeline that does nothing (I tried a console.writeline in a other function to be sure I looked in the good console...) but if I try the solution of Sándor Jankovics, I enter in my function (I thing) but I have an infinite loop and my computer crash.

Answer (score 1):

Here I think the basic idea is wrong. Agnular change detection will run on every event and will try to reeavluate your expression, and each time it will call you api. What you could do is

change HTML to a static varible

```
<button [hidden]="postIsHidden" mat-icon-button>
                <mat-icon  (click)="down(post.id)">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
 </button>
```

and for the .ts file

```
    postIsHidden:boolean=true

    ngOnInit(){
       this.getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus(/*your post id*/)
    }

    getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus(postId : number){
        this.postService.getVoteForPostConnectedUserPlus(postId, this.getCurrentUserId)
               .subscribe((result)=>this.postIsHidden);
            }
```

Comment: wow I have an infinite loop when I do that, it look like it's doing the linq requete over and over. And this might work for my first post but not for the answer , my post contain a list of post (answers) so I have the id of the first post but I have button for every answer. I have to pass the id of the post. (I have to do something quite similar to stackoverflow)